# Sequence of functions from an arbitrary topological space to another arbitrary topological space

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, reference-request

Is(are) there any known paper(s) or book(s) which discussed the Theory of Sequence of Functions from an arbitrary topological space to another arbitrary topological space? More specifically, by the Theory of Sequence of Functions from an arbitrary topological space to another arbitrary topological space I mean the study of pointwise and uniform convergence and related aspects of sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $f_n:X\to Y$ and both $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary topological spaces. If there is(are), can some references be given?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you're going to get any useful responses unless you edit this question to make it more specific... It's not clear at all clear to me what you are looking for

Comment: @MikeF: Can you tell me exactly which part of the question is not specific?

Comment: Well... huge swaths of analysis and topology are devoted to studying various different kinds of sequences of functions between different kinds of spaces (metric spaces, topological vector spaces, or other things) and different kinds of convergence properties, or accumulation properties (uniform, pointwise, with respect to many different linear topologies) of sequences of those functions... It seems a bit like asking "are there any history books or papers which discuss the lives of historical persons" or something.

Comment: @MikeF: But is there any literature devoted to studying different kinds of sequences of functions between the topological spaces, not on something special as metric spaces, topological vector spaces?

Comment: @user170039 I am not sure if there exists something like this in a general context, because usually sequences are not enough to understand the topology in general cases; [nets do it better](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261404)

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba: Then studies on nets of functions?

Comment: @user170039 I don't use nets in my normal days, so I can't answer this last question. However, I can recommend two references on function spaces: [Tkachuk's book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/A_Cp_Theory_Problem_Book.html?id=EcINw8FHIAoC&redir_esc=y) and [Okuyama and Terada's chapter](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924650908701570)  of the book Topics in General Topology.

Also, I think it is worth noting that in order to discuss uniform convergence you need a structure called [uniformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Comment: One place to begin (in an overview and reference sort of way) is Eric Schechter's [**Handbook of Analysis and Its Foundations**](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/ccc/excerpts/contents.html).